# Adding x error bars to a scatter plot in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, errorbar

I have a scatter plot in tableau:

[image]

I am looking to add error bars to the points but cant find how to do this. I would need to specify the lower limits and upper limmits (i.e. not just a fixed percentage of the value). The only thing I can find is adding y errors in the form of a gant plot but this isnt helpuful (I dont think) as I only need x errors.

Comment: post sample data

Comment: I dont think the what the data is would make any difference to the method of how to display x error bars but here is a random sample of 10 points and some errors.
`
xdata ydata xerror yerror
0.4853 0.1698 0.121330967 0.025480916
0.2618 0.9648 0.065461922 0.144720871
0.3529 0.6659 0.088227775 0.099898408
0.1577 0.0840 0.039444143 0.012606899
0.0482     0.5167 0.012061576 0.077506888
0.5162 0.3000 0.129051591 0.045012529
0.1359 0.5211 0.033986152 0.078176976
0.6925 0.4865 0.173146067 0.07298157
0.5802 0.0513 0.145054827 0.007701638
0.5936 0.1599 0.148418241 0.023995017
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible with a combination of using Measure Values (to show lines between the error ranges) and a dual axis (to overlay the X values on the lines)

[image]

See [sample workbook](https://public.tableau.com/profile/alex.blakemore#!/vizhome/scatter_15756046860720/Sheet1)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am in the unfortunate position where the version of Tableau I have at work is too old to open your workbook. I am at the stage where I have points plotted for the min x err value and max x err value. I have then combined them using a dual axis and synchronised the axes. However, I cant get the path to go between the two values the line instead follows the path of increasing x for each data ser (xerr and yerr).

Comment: Ignore ^^ I managed to change the version I opened the work book with and have it all working now. Thank you again.

Comment: @Iain McL FYI I posted an update that shows a few alternative implementations and (no longer) inflates the length of the error bars in the sample data